# Difference between webMethods SAG and web service?

Tags: webmethods

Can someone tel me about the difference between webmethods software ag and web service soa.

What is the plus while using webmethods.

Suggest some tutorial to learn this technologies.

Comment: I don't understand the question. WebMethods is a software AG product, while Web Service is a general term representing protocols. So, nothing to compare.

Comment: What is the webMethods.

Comment: Is it possible that you're confusing .net web methods with SoftwareAG's product, which coincidentally has the same name? Or maybe with javax.jws.WebMethod?